# Getting a pipe reference into a task

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two classes, Task1 and Task2. Task1 should read from a TCP/IP port and send up a pipe to Task2. Task2 should return the data to Task1 who echoes this to the client. This is just an experiment. Task2 will eventually process the data and send to another piece of hardware across a serial line. Task1 and Task2 should run on separate cores. I cannot see how to get the pipe reference into the tasks. It is not really necessary Task1 be different from the application. Just has to monitor a TCP/IP port and a pipe asynchronously.

Task1

```py
import asyncio
import os
from multiprocessing import Pipe
import sys


class Task1:
    def __init__(self, pipe):
        self.comm_pipe = pipe

    async def run(self, reader, writer):
        while True:
            data = await reader.read(100)
            if data:
                self.comm_pipe.send(data)
            else:
                break
            if self.comm_pipe.poll():
                data_from_pipe = self.comm_pipe.recv()
                writer.write(data_from_pipe)
                await writer.drain()
        writer.close()


async def task_main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        lambda r, w: Task1(?????).run(r, w),
        '0.0.0.0', 4365)

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


def main(pipe):
    asyncio.run(task_main())
```

Task2

```py
import asyncio
from multiprocessing import Pipe


class Task2:
    def __init__(self, pipe):
        self.pipe = pipe

    async def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.pipe.poll():
                data = self.pipe.recv()
                reversed_data = data[::-1]
                self.pipe.send(reversed_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    task2 = Task2(????????)
    asyncio.run(task2.run())
```

App

```py
import multiprocessing
import Task1
import Task2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parent_pipe1, child_pipe1 = multiprocessing.Pipe()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Task1.main, args=(parent_pipe1,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Task2.main, args=(child_pipe1,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: Well, you aren't going to be running Task1.py and Task2.py by themselves.  They're just imported.  Your calls to `mutiprocessing.Process` are going to pass in the pipe handles, as a parameter to `Task1.main` and `Task2.main`.  It's also not clear why you are mixing multiprocessing and asyncio here.  It shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you. Apparently, I do not understand the difference. I thought multiprocessing allowed use of the cores available and asyncio simply allowed waiting on I/O event to happen. I looked for a way to register a callback for I./O events but did not see one. Why would Task & Task2 not run? I thought multiprocessing.Process actually started them as tasks?

Comment: @TimRoberts I think I understand your question now. And please excuse the crappy formatting of the original post. There is a good reason for using asyncio and MP together, logic tells me that breaking this application into four classes is the best approach. At least in the C/C++/C# world where I have been for many years. I am still new to the intricacies of python. While I appreciate your response, some suggestions as to why I am going in the wrong direction would be helpful.

Comment: You're starting up two subprocesses.  Those are independent processes with their own copy of Python and their memory spaces, unrelated to the original process.  Because of that, they are ALREADY running in parallel.  asyncio adds nothing.  I'll see if I can come up with an example.

Comment: @TimRoberts I get it! I was way over complicating things, I think. asyncio, gives the impression of concurrency by allowing an event loop to keep going until an event happens. You are right, since these are independent processes, they can block. However, this forces Task1 to not process the Queue until something comes in from the socket, I believe. As I really need to asynchronously process the socket and the queue, multiprocessing is the wrong solution. That is why I tried to use both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that does what you are trying to do (a "reversing echo" server), but without asyncio.  Asyncio isn't necessary, because each "task" is already in its own process.  Each one can block without affecting the rest.

I used a `multiprocessing.Queue` because I was doing some experimenting, but you could also use a `multiprocessing.Pipe`.

```
import os
import sys
import socketserver
import multiprocessing


class Task1(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print("Task1.handle")
        while True:
            data = self.request.recv(100).strip()
            print('got',data)
            if not data:
                break
            queue2.put(data)
            data = queue1.get()
            self.request.sendall(data)

def task1_main(pin, pout):
    with socketserver.TCPServer(('0.0.0.0',4365), Task1) as server:
        addr = server.socket.getsockname()
        print(f'Serving on {addr}')
        server.serve_forever()


class Task2:
    def __init__(self, pin, pout):
        self.qin = pin
        self.qout = pout

    def run(self):
        print("Task2.run")
        while True:
            data = self.qin.get()
            reversed_data = data[::-1]
            print('sending',reversed_data)
            self.qout.put(reversed_data)

def task2_main(pin, pout):
    task2 = Task2(pin, pout)
    task2.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue2 = multiprocessing.Queue()

    print("task1")
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=task1_main, args=(queue1,queue2))
    print("task2")
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=task2_main, args=(queue2,queue1))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: This shows nicely how multiprocessing works and I thank you for the example. It works well, but as I suspected it waits on input data from the socket and sends up the data a queue and then reads the other queue. While this functionality can be added to the "main" application code, I really do need a separate process for a second task. It is CPU intensive. It also has two queues to monitor but as you show here, this will work just fine for that work.

Comment: Now, this task COULD be done with asyncio within a single process.  I started to write that, but this was easier...

Comment: Yes, it looks like it was easier! It gave me a lesson! Now I understand how to create a separate process and move data back and forth. The trick now is to better understand asyncio, the event loop, and how to essentially put "awaits" on socket and a pipe., thus the processing for each is truly asynchronous. If you have an idea and want to teach a very old dog a new trick I am all ears. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have been playing with your example. If I were to separate the tasks and the main loop into 3 classes. How do I get the references to queue1 and queue2 into the Task1 and Task2 class?

Comment: I did that for Task2.  I passed the queues as arguments to `task2_main`, and had `task2_main` pass them to the constructor.  For `Task1`, I just used them as globals. because the instance is created by the socketserver.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I see that now and have broken the example into 3 classes in an effort to better understand how I clean up if the client closes the socket and the exit the application. Still working on that part. So far all I can find is StreamRequestHandlerFinish so I am still figuring this out.

Comment: The `socketserver` class will handle the client closing the socket.  `Task1.handle` is only called when more data is available.  It doesn't hold any state.

Comment: Thanks. There seems to be many ways of handling the socket. Here it is a method called handle, but it is not really a stream as I cannot use readuntil(). Another example the Task1 class is derived from asyncio.Protocol, so I have connection_made(), data_received() and connection_lost. But this is not a StreamReader either. Frankly, I have read so many web pages of documentation on Python and tried so many examples I am lost.